# Dynamically building conditions in JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jooq

I have an endpoint that receives a string with all the columns and value they want to filter by. Here's an example of what the filters param looks like: `?filter=active=true,type=ADMIN`, basically each filter is separated by a `,` and then the column name and filter value are separated by an `=` So I made this method to dynamically build a condition statement with all the different filters for any table:

```
public Condition mapFilterToCondition(String tableName, String filters) {
    Condition condition = DSL.trueCondition();
    String[] filterFields = filters.split(",");
    Table<?> table = PUBLIC.getTable(tableName);
    Field<?>[] fields = table.fields();
    for(String filterField : filterFields) {
        String[] filter = filterField.split("=");
        for(Field<?> field : fields) {
            String fieldName = CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, filter[0]);
            if(field.getName().equals(fieldName)) {
                if(field.getType() == String.class) {
                    condition.and(table.field(field).like(filter[1]));
                } else if (Boolean.valueOf(filter[1])) {
                    condition.and(table.field(field).isTrue());
                } else if (!Boolean.valueOf(filter[1])) {
                    condition.and(table.field(field).isFalse());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return condition;
}
```

I then use the condition built by this method to call a repository that makes the sql request:

```
public List<UserAccount> findAllByFilter(Condition condition, Pageable pageable) {
    return dsl.select()
            .from(USER_ACCOUNT)
            .where(condition)
            .limit(pageable.getPageSize())
            .offset((int) pageable.getOffset())
            .fetchInto(UserAccount.class);
}
```

As I understood, the condition should have something like this:

`.where(USER_ACCOUNT.TYPE.like("ADMIN"))`
`.where(USER_ACCOUNT.ACTIVE.isTrue())`

based on the condition I built, but whenever I make the call, it returns every single user, not taking into account the filters. While debugging I found out the condition is never changing from `1 = 1`, which is the value it has from `DSL.trueCondition();`, so my question is how I should be handling the construction of this condition? Am I using `condition.and(...)` wrong, or should I be using something else instead?

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/admin", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity listAll(String filters, Pageable pageable) {
    Condition condition = filterMapService.mapFilterToCondition("user_account", filters);
    List<UserAccount> adminAccounts = userAccountRepository.findAllByFilter(condition, pageable);
    if (adminAccounts.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
    List<AdminDTO> accounts = adminAccounts.stream()
            .map(account -> modelMapper.map(account, AdminDTO.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(accounts, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: The example you supplied `filter=active=true,type=ADMIN` seems to be improperly formatted. Can you supply other inputs you have provided?

Comment: What do you mean by improperly formatted?

Comment: Are you supplying the string: "filter=active=true, type=ADMIN" to your method `mapFilterToCondition`?

Comment: I've edited the question with the controller that calls the methods. The filters variable is a request param, but I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with the condition part.

Comment: If no conditions are being added, then it is likely that the problem is  coming from the lines `String fieldName = CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, filter[0]);
            if(field.getName().equals(fieldName))`. Be sure that the fields in your table match the field names set by the first above line. (I'm unfamiliar with the framework you are using, but `field.getName()` may return uppercase Strings for example.

Comment: Using the debugger the code definitely reaches these lines: `condition.and(table.field(field).like(filter[1]));`, `condition.and(table.field(field).isTrue());`. So they are being called.

Comment: Change all references to `condition=condition.and(...)`. I looked at the documentation and those methods return `Condition` objects that reflect the new filters (rather than altering the supplied `Condition` object).

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what was happening, can you answer the question with this comment so I can mark it as solved. Thank you you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change all references to

```
condition.and(...)
```

to:

```
condition = condition.and(...)
```

The value of the Condition object is not actually getting updated.

Comment: Absolutely. For more info, there's a section in the manual that talks about mutability / immutability of various `QueryPart` types: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/dsl-and-non-dsl